# Can't send Message from Server( C++ Socket)

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm new to `C++ Socket` and my Server can't send message to its client. The `send()` function return -1 always and it seems to have a problem with `accpSocket`. However Client can do that smoothly and I don't know what's wrong. Please help me thank you so much!

Server

```
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<WS2tcpip.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sdkddkver.h>
#include<winsock.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SOCKET serverSocket, acceptSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    int port = 2403;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;

    //Step 1: Set up dll

    WORD versionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(versionRequested, &wsaData);
    
    if (wsaerr)
        cout << "The winsock dll not found";
    else {
        cout << "The winsock dll found\n";
        cout << "Winsock dll status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << endl;
    }

    //Step 2: Set up server socket

    serverSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Error at socket: " << WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Server socket successfull!\n";


    //Step 3: Binding socket
    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    service.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Binding failed! " << WSAGetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Binding complete!\n";
    

    // Step 4: Listen to the connections
    if (listen(serverSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Listen failed! " << WSAGetLastError();
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Waiting for connections ...";


    SOCKET accpSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (accpSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Accepting failed! " << WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
        cout << "Accept connection!\n";

    

    char recvMess[2000];
    char sendMess[2000];
    int byterecv = recv(accpSocket, recvMess, sizeof(recvMess), 0);

    cout << "Client: " << recvMess << endl;
    cout << "Server: ";

    cin.getline(sendMess, 2000);
    int bytesend = send(acceptSocket, sendMess, 2000, 0);

    if (bytesend <= 0)
        cout << "Unsent";
    

    

    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
#include<iostream>
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<WS2tcpip.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int port = 2403;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;

    SOCKET clientSocket;
    WORD versionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    wsaerr = WSAStartup(versionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaerr)
        cout << "Winsock dll not found!";
    else {
        cout << "Winsock dll is ok!\n";
        cout << "Status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << endl;
    }

    clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Set up client socket failed" << WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Set up complete!\n";

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (inet_pton(clientService.sin_family, "127.0.0.1", &clientService.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        cout << "Invalid address!";
        return -1;
    }

    if ((connect(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService))) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Connection failed!\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Connection complete!\n";

    char sendMess[2000];
    char recvMess[2000];

    cout << "Client: ";
    cin.getline(sendMess, 2000);

    int bytesend = send(clientSocket, sendMess, 2000, 0);

    int byterecv = recv(clientSocket, recvMess, 2000, 0);
    if (byterecv <= 0)
        cout << "Nothing";
    else
        cout << "Server" << recvMess << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A failed `send` looks like a good time to make another call to ` WSAGetLastError` to get more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int bytesend = send(acceptSocket, sendMess, 2000, 0);
```

is not sending to a connected socket. `acceptSocket` was defined at the top of `main` and then ignored up until the call to `send`

As a general rule of thumb, keep variable definition close to first use.

In the server at

```cpp
SOCKET serverSocket, acceptSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         Killlllll meeeeee!!!!
```

remove `acceptSocket` to prevent future mistakes and in

```
int bytesend = send(acceptSocket, sendMess, 2000, 0);
```

replace `acceptSocket` with the socket that was actually accepted, `accpSocket`.

Side notes:

Never ignore the return codes.

```
int byterecv = recv(accpSocket, recvMess, sizeof(recvMess), 0);
```

could fail and return -1 or return 0 if the socket was disconnected, yet the program will still

```
cout << "Client: " << recvMess << endl;
```

And worse, there's no guarantee that `recvMess` will be null-terminated, `recv` on a streaming socket gives you what the socket has available or becomes available up to the maximum number of bytes requested, so if there is any data read, make sure `byterecv` is a valid index in `recvMess` by only reading `sizeof(recvMess) - 1` bytes and then forcing termination with `recvMess[byterecv] = '\0';` before printing.

`send(acceptSocket, sendMess, 2000, 0);` sends all 2000 bytes of sendMess regardless of how many bytes were read with `cin.getline(sendMess, 2000);`. Use

```
send(acceptSocket, sendMess, cin.gcount(), 0);
```

instead. Add on an extra byte (`cin.gcount() + 1`) if you want to send the null terminator.

Comment: Such a basic mistake that i didn't realize and the knowledge about receiving the message is great too. Thank you so much